# python fuzzy regex with nested or regex

Tags: python, regex, fuzzy-search, pypi-regex

I'm trying to do some fuzzy matching on a string of DNA reads.  I'd like to allow for up to 1 substitution error while at the same time allowing a particular basepair to be one of two options (A or G in this case).

I've started with the following:

```
>>> regex.findall("([A|G]TTAGATACCCTGGTAGTCC){0<=s<=1}", "ATTAGATACCCTGGTAGTCA")
['ATTAGATACCCTGGTAGTCA']
```

matches as expected because I'm matching against the exact string

```
>>> regex.findall("([A|G]TTAGATACCCTGGTAGTCC){0<=s<=1}", "GTTAGATACCCTGGTAGTCA")
['GTTAGATACCCTGGTAGTCA']
```

matches as expected because I'm matching against the exact string except the first base pair has been switched from an A to a G (allowed)

```
>>> regex.findall("([A|G]TTAGATACCCTGGTAGTCC){0<=s<=1}", "GTTAGATACCCTGGTAGTCx")
['GTTAGATACCCTGGTAGTCx']
```

matches as expected because a single substitution occurs (C->x)

```
>>> regex.findall("([A|G]TTAGATACCCTGGTAGTCC){0<=s<=1}", "xTTAGATACCCTGGTAGTCx")
[]
```

does not match (as expected) because there are two substitutions

```
>>> regex.findall("([A|G]TTAGATACCCTGGTAGTCC){0<=s<=1}", "xTTAGATACCCTGGTAGTCA")
[]
```

**should have matched**, since the first basepair error (x instead of A or G) should have been counted as a substitution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have **two** substitutions in your last example: the first basepair has been substituted with an `x` while the last has been changed to an `A`. You only allow one substitution, so there's no match.